# SQL арифметическое вычитание

Tags: sql, oracle

Как мне это реализовать?

Мне нужна сумма всех значений из столбца `PPLAN`, и из этой суммы нужно отнять значение `PPLAN`.

Допустим, вся сумма = `89 473,79`.
На первой строке будет значение `89473,79 - 2182,29 = 87291.5`,
на второй будет `89473,79 - 2182,29 - 2182,29 = 85109.21`
и т.д., пока не будет уже в конце `0`.

Количество строк всегда разное, т.к. это зависит обычно от периода месяцев, может быть 20 или 40, к примеру. Поэтому решил отталкиваться от всей суммы.

Как мне можно поставить счетчик? Или сама логика решения задачи некорректна?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что значит первая строка, вторая... Вы ведь в курсе, что порядок строк не гарантируется?

Comment: А у вас действительно MySQL ? как то картинка очень сильно на pl/sql developer смахивает, а это oracle и решение в нем совершенно не такое как в MySQL ... И да, необходимо указать в каком порядке сортировке записей определять какая из них первая, вторая и т.п.

Comment: в mysql 8 решение с оконными функциями должно быть весьма простым

Comment: @teran да оно и в более ранних версиях несложное, выдавать предыдущее значение переменной, перед тем как прибавить к ней pplan при сортировке в обратном порядке. только я ооочень сильно сомневаюсь, что вопрос действительно по MySQL, а автор вопроса походу задал вопрос и ушел. Ну а в oracle да, будет оконная функция

Comment: Да получить сумму в подзапросе, и вся недолга... вычитай не хочу. В твоём случае вычитать сумму с накоплением. Но гораздо быстрее в подзапросе получить, наоборот, сумму по этому полю с накоплением, но при обратной сортировке, а во внешнем запросе просто реверсировать сортировку.

Comment: @Mike Нажал Enter раньше времени... уже дополнил коммент.

Comment: @Mike да вы правы, это в pl/sql developer
мне необходимо осуществить оконную функцию? каким образом подскажите пож-та

Comment: Под номерами строк я имел ввиду что будет еще столбец, в котором будет столько же строк , и на каждой строке по порядку должны быть вычитания от предыдущих значений

например, 1 15/09/2017   87291.5
2 15/10/2017  85109.21
3 15/11/2017 82926.92

Comment: @zharzhanov.miras под какими номерами строк ? Их вам выдает pl/sql developer, в бд их нет. может все таки например по возрастанию duedate, это было бы логично

Comment: @Mike да, вы правы под возрастанием duedate

Answer (score 1):

Фактически вам нужна сумма всех последующих строк относительно текущей в указанной сортировке. Так что можно ничего не вычитать и получить сумму прямо по требуемому диапазону строк:

```
select T.*,
       nvl(
        sum(pplan)
          over(order by duedate rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
       ,0)
  from Table T
```

В последней строке возвращается NULL т.к. следующей 1 строки уже нет, превращаем его в 0 с помощью nvl.

Информацию по работе предложения over() можно найти в документации по [аналитическим функциям Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

Comment: Могу ли записать ваш запрос как :
to_char(sum(pplan) over () - sum(pplan) over (order by /*duedate*/ tt.rs_dd )) as  t_pplan в select?

Comment: @zharzhanov.miras Можете конечно, и даже мой вариант, весь nvl целиком внутрь помещаете. Оно конечно длиннее, но мне как то больше нравится, чем вычисление двух сумм и нахождение разницы, работы БД меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы такое предложил:

```
select sum(pplan) over () - sum(pplan) over (order by duedate)
  from mytable
```

Первое `sum(pplan) over ()` - это просто полная сумма, а `sum(pplan) over (order by duedate)` - это сумма с накоплением, соответственно, у вас в каждой следующей строке будут значения `89473,79`, `89473,79 - 2182,29`, `89473,79 - 2182,29 - 2182,29` и так далее.

Comment: а можно это как то через to_char записать? без селекта

Comment: @zharzhanov.miras В смысле? Вы отформатировать результат хотите? Давно бы попробовали уже. Конечно можно, все выражение целиком запихиваете в `to_char`, оно преобразуется в строку.